# Switching users in remote ssh command execution

Tags: ssh, su

I'm wondering why executing `su` in an `ssh` command does not appear to be having the desired effect of switching users before executing the subsequent commands, as illustrated below:

The following command:

```
bob@server1:~$ sudo ssh -n root@server2 "su bob; env"
```

Produces the following output:

```
...
USER=root
PWD=/root
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
...
```

I expected the output to reflect that which user bob would have observed, however it is the environment of the root user. I have found, however, that the following command achieves the desired effect:

```
bob@server1:~$ sudo ssh -n root@server2 "su bob -c \"env\""
```

This command produces the following output:

```
...
USER=bob
PWD=/root
HOME=/users/bob
LOGNAME=bob
...
```

I would like to understand why the first way (executing `"su bob; env"`) does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider first what the `su` command does: it starts a new shell as the target user.  Ignoring ssh for a moment, just become `root` on your local system and try running something like this:

```
su someuser; env
```

What happens?  You will get a shell as `someuser`, and when you *exit* that shell, the `env` command executes in `root`'s environment.  If you wanted to run the `env` command as `someuser`, you would need:

```
su someuser -c env
```

This instructs `su` to run the `env` command as `someuser`.

When you run:

```
sudo ssh -n root@server2 "su bob; env"
```

The shell spawned by `su` exits immediately, because you've disabled stdin (with `-n`), and the `env` command executes in `root`'s environment, just like in this example.